# client sent invalid header line in Nginx

Tags: nginx

in Nginx error log file , getting error as

> client sent invalid header line: "LocalDBUser_CREATE|USERNAME: User1"
>   while reading client request headers

How to fix this issue.

My Nginx Conf file is

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}     
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
        upstream uic_entry {
    server 127.0.0.1:4005;
        }

 server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  xxx.yyy.com;
        underscores_in_headers on;
            large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503         http_504;
           proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;
           proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
             proxy_read_timeout 200;

    location / {
        #root   html;
        #index  index.html index.htm;
        #return 503;
                proxy_pass          http://uic_entry;
    }
```

Please let me know how to fix the error

Answer (score 10):

I guess, you need directive [`ignore_invalid_headers off`](http://nginx.org/r/ignore_invalid_headers).

Comment: Add it, or to remove it?  It seems that OP needs to *allow* for invalid headers? it'd be good if you explained that his headers contain an invalid character, and that as long as the application doesn't need that header, OP can make nginx ignore the malformed header...

Answer (score 6):

In this case you need:
`underscores_in_headers on;`

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers

> Valid names are composed of English letters, digits, hyphens, and
>   possibly underscores

Answer (score 2):

i had same problem. you need just remove from config of vhost

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```